# "No space left on device" error while running apt-get update

Tags: apt, 18.04, gnome, package-management, snap

I use a dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 setup. While there is enough space on the filesystem, running `sudo apt-get update` results in multiple `No space left on device` errors.

Running `df -i` gives me this output:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            998574    629  997945    1% /dev
tmpfs          1004542   1090 1003452    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1921360 295775 1625585   16% /
tmpfs          1004542     88 1004454    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1004542      3 1004539    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1004542     18 1004524    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1         271    271       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/317
/dev/loop2       27707  27707       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop3       39455  39455       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop4       10041  10041       0  100% /snap/core18/1098
/dev/loop5        1550   1550       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop6       12823  12823       0  100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop0         354    354       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop7       27707  27707       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop8        1574   1574       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop10        734    734       0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop9         354    354       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/73
/dev/loop11      12827  12827       0  100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/nvme0n1p1       0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop12      10040  10040       0  100% /snap/core18/1144
/dev/loop13        271    271       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/sda4      9617408  65026 9552382    1% /home
tmpfs          1004542     40 1004502    1% /run/user/1000
```

It seems that /snap is taking up all the inodes, but from what I can tell I can't remove them to release the inodes. What can I do to fix this?

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  1.9M  783M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   29G   11G   17G  39% /
tmpfs           3.9G   60M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/317
/dev/loop2      150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop3       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop4       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1098
/dev/loop5      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop6       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop0      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop7      150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop8      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop10     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop9      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/73
/dev/loop11      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   34M  223M  14% /boot/efi
/dev/loop12      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1144
/dev/loop13      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/sda4       144G   24G  113G  18% /home
tmpfs           785M   56K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
```

The output of `sudo apt-get update` is here (see also the [full output](https://pastebin.com/ZKgNhxYH)):

```
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  500  No space left on device [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  No space left on device [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The output of `fsck -f` on \ (which is on my SSD):

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: 295789/1921360 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 2936226/7680000 blocks
```

The output of `fsck -f` on \home (which is on my HDD):

```
/dev/sda4: 66280/9617408 files (2.3% non-contiguous), 7054556/38448730 blocks
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99142/discussion-on-question-by-favre-no-space-left-on-device-error-while-running-ap).